# Case-insensitive Array#include?

Tags: ruby, string

I want to know what's the best way to make the `String.include?` methods ignore case. Currently I'm doing the following. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
a = "abcDE"
b = "CD"
result = a.downcase.include? b.downcase
```

Edit:
How about `Array.include?`. All elements of the array are strings.

Comment: Do you want to see if the array has any string that is **exactly like** a particular one (case-insensitive), or if the array has any string that **includes** the particular one (case-insensitive)?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

### Summary

If you are only going to test a single word against an array, or if the contents of your array changes frequently, the fastest answer is Aaron's:

```
array.any?{ |s| s.casecmp(mystr)==0 }
```

If you are going to test many words against a static array, it's far better to use a variation of farnoy's answer: create a copy of your array that has all-lowercase versions of your words, and use `include?`. (This assumes that you can spare the memory to create a mutated copy of your array.)

```
# Do this once, or each time the array changes
downcased = array.map(&:downcase)

# Test lowercase words against that array
downcased.include?( mystr.downcase )
```

Even better, create a [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) from your array.

```
# Do this once, or each time the array changes
downcased = Set.new array.map(&:downcase)

# Test lowercase words against that array
downcased.include?( mystr.downcase )
```

*My original answer below is a very poor performer and generally not appropriate.*

### Benchmarks

Following are benchmarks for looking for 1,000 words with random casing in an array of slightly over 100,000 words, where 500 of the words will be found and 500 will not.

- The 'regex' text is my answer here, using `any?`.
- The 'casecmp' test is Arron's answer, using `any?` from my comment.
- The 'downarray' test is farnoy's answer, re-creating a new downcased array for each of the 1,000 tests.
- The 'downonce' test is farnoy's answer, but pre-creating the lookup array once only.
- The 'set_once' test is creating a `Set` from the array of downcased strings, once before testing.

```
                user     system      total        real
regex      18.710000   0.020000  18.730000 ( 18.725266)
casecmp     5.160000   0.000000   5.160000 (  5.155496)
downarray  16.760000   0.030000  16.790000 ( 16.809063)
downonce    0.650000   0.000000   0.650000 (  0.643165)
set_once    0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.038955)
```

If you can create a single downcased copy of your array once to perform many lookups against, farnoy's answer is the best (assuming you **must** use an array). If you can create a `Set`, though, do that.

If you like, [examine the benchmarking code](https://gist.github.com/Phrogz/8bd5f0eccfb90986977f1a55207fb46f).

---

### Original Answer

I *(originally said that I)* would personally create a case-insensitive regex (for a string literal) and use that:

```
re = /\A#{Regexp.escape(str)}\z/i # Match exactly this string, no substrings
all = array.grep(re)              # Find all matching strings…
any = array.any?{ |s| s =~ re }   #  …or see if any matching string is present
```

Using `any?` can be slightly faster than `grep` as it can exit the loop as soon as it finds a single match.

Comment: Saw some interesting answers here, didn't realise my was the fastest one. Thanks for comparing all that.

Comment: Rather than `s.casecmp(mystr)==0`, you can do `s.casecmp?(mystr)`.  `casecmp?` returns "true if str and other_other_str are equal after Unicode case folding, false if they are not equal, and nil if other_str is not a string." (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-casecmp-3F)

Comment: `casecmp` works perfectly! example: `['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird'].any?{ |s| s.casecmp('cat')==0 }` - it returns `true `

Answer (score 13):

For an array, use:

```
array.map(&:downcase).include?(string)
```

Regexps are very slow and should be avoided.

Comment: Without any benchmarks, I'd wager that using a case-insensitive regex to search through an array of strings will be far _faster_ than what you have here.

Comment: I must somewhat eat my words. :) As shown in the benchmark added to my answer, re-creating the downcase array for each test performs only slightly slower then my regex-based solution. If many lookups are needed against the same dataset, however, this answer is the best if you pre-create the `array.map(&:downcase)` and test against that.

Comment: well, I must admit I wasn't sure about regexps, so kudos for the benchmarks. The answer should be yours for the extra effort though :)

Comment: Goodness no, the accepted answer should be the best answer for future visitors skimming! :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [casecmp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-casecmp) to do your comparison, ignoring case.

```
"abcdef".casecmp("abcde")     #=> 1
"aBcDeF".casecmp("abcdef")    #=> 0
"abcdef".casecmp("abcdefg")   #=> -1
"abcdef".casecmp("ABCDEF")    #=> 0
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, how to use `casecmp` with the `include?` method? Thanks.

Comment: Use [`array.any?{ |s| s.casecmp("mystr")==0 }`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F).

Answer (score 4):

```
class String
    def caseinclude?(x)
        a.downcase.include?(x.downcase)
    end
end
```

Comment: +1 for monkeypatching fun, but -1 because this will perform substring searching, when the (revised) question seems to be asking for case-insensitive _exact_ string matching in an array of strings.

Answer (score 3):

> my_array.map!{|c| c.downcase.strip}

where `map!` changes my_array, `map` instead returns a new array.

Answer (score -2):

To farnoy in my case your example doesn't work for me.  I'm actually looking to do this with a "substring" of any.

Here's my test case.

```
x = "<TD>", "<tr>", "<BODY>"
y = "td"
x.collect { |r| r.downcase }.include? y
=> false
x[0].include? y
=> false
x[0].downcase.include? y
=> true
```

Your case works with an exact case-insensitive match.

```
a = "TD", "tr", "BODY"
b = "td"
a.collect { |r| r.downcase }.include? b
=> true
```

I'm still experimenting with the other suggestions here.

---EDIT INSERT AFTER HERE---

I found the answer.  Thanks to [Drew Olsen](http://drewolson.wordpress.com/2007/03/23/5-things-you-can-do-with-a-ruby-array-in-one-line-plus-a-free-bonus/)

```
var1 = "<TD>", "<tr>","<BODY>"
=> ["<TD>", "<tr>", "<BODY>"]
var2 = "td"
=> "td"
var1.find_all{|item| item.downcase.include?(var2)}
=> ["<TD>"]
var1[0] = "<html>"
=> "<html>"
var1.find_all{|item| item.downcase.include?(var2)}
=> []
```