# Is there a nice way to check if a string contains at least one string from an array of strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string

`string.include?(other_string)` is used to check if a string contains another string. Is there a nice way to check if a string contains at least one string from an array of strings?

```
string_1 = "a monkey is an animal. dogs are fun"

arrays_of_strings_to_check_against = ['banana', 'fruit', 'animal', 'dog']
```

This would return `true`, because `string_1` contains the string `'animal'`. If we remove `'animal'` from `arrays_of_strings_to_check_against`, it would return `false`.

Note that the string `'dog'` from `arrays_of_strings_to_check_against` should not match `'dogs'` from `string_1`, because it has to be a complete match.

I'm using Rails 3.2.0 and Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333952/case-insensitive-arrayinclude

Comment: Homework question. I did almost exactly the same one before...

Comment: How about case-sensitivity: should "apple" in your array match "Apple" in the string?

Comment: @texasbruce Not a homework question. I'm using code that does this in my app already, just interested to see some better ways to do it in Ruby.

Comment: @Phrogz It should be case insensitive. Should have included that in the question, will edit it in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
arrays_of_strings_to_check_against.map{ |o| string_1 =~ /\b#{Regexp.escape(o)}\b/ }.any?
```

Or even:

```
arrays_of_strings_to_check_against.any?{ |o| string_1 =~ /\b#{Regexp.escape(o)}\b/ }
```

Comment: why not just `.any?{ |o| string_1.include? o }` ?

Comment: @ChrisRice Yep, that's more simple.

Comment: @Phrogz I missed that, just fixed.

Comment: @pguardiario That will match `dogs` for `dog`.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that. I posted another solution instead.

Answer (score 3):

If `array_of_strings_to_check_against` contains only whole words, and not multi-word strings, you can `&` the two arrays together. If the result has length > 0, there was a match. Prior to `.split(' ')`, however, you must remove non-word, non-space characters. Otherwise, in this case it would fail because `animal.` (with `.`) isn't in your array.

```
if (string_1.gsub(/[^\w\s]/).split(' ') & array_of_strings_to_check_against).length > 0
  puts "Match!!"
end
```

#### Update after comments: case-insensitive version

```
if (string_1.downcase.gsub(/[^\w\s]/).split(' ') & array_of_strings_to_check_against).length > 0
  puts "Match!!"
end
```

Comment: you'd have to include any sort of non-alphabet characters to use as delimiters, otherwise `animal` would not match.

Comment: This answer does not cover the (recently-mentioned) need for case-insensitivity. You'd want to throw a `.downcase` onto the string before the `gsub`. However, a big +1 for using `gsub` as an enumerator and the fun usage of `Array#&` to check for set intersection.

Answer (score 3):

```
str1  = "a monkey is an animal. dogs are fun"
str2  = "a monkey is a primate. dogs are fun"
words = %w[banana fruit animal dog]
word_test = /\b(?:#{ words.map{|w| Regexp.escape(w) }.join("|") })\b/i

p str1 =~ word_test,  #=> 15
  str2 =~ word_test   #=> nil
```

If you get `nil` there was no match; otherwise you'll get an integer (which you can treat just like `true`) that is the index of the offset where the match occurred.

If you absolutely must have `true` or `false`, you can do:

```
any_match = !!(str =~ word_test)
```

The regular expression created by interpolation is:

```
/\b(?:banana|fruit|animal|dog)\b/i
```

…where the `\b` matches a "word boundary", thus preventing `dog` from matching in `dogs`.

**Edit**: The answer above no longer uses `Regexp.union` since that creates a case-sensitive regex, while the question requires case-insensitive.

Alternatively, we can force everything to lowercase before the test to gain case-insensitivity:

```
words = %w[baNanA Fruit ANIMAL dog]
word_test = /\b#{ Regexp.union(words.map(&:downcase)) }\b/
p str1.downcase =~ word_test,
  str2.downcase =~ word_test
```

Comment: @ben I've edited this answer to account for case-insensitivity.

Answer (score 2):

`Regexp.union` is your friend in this case. Consider:

```
# the words we're looking for...
target_words = %w[ore sit ad sint est lore]

search_text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'

# define a search ignoring case that looks for partial words...
partial_words_regex = /#{ Regexp.union(target_words).source }/i
partial_words_regex.to_s # => "(?i-mx:ore|sit|ad|sint|est|lore)"

# define a search ignoring case that looks for whole words...
whole_words_regex = /\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(target_words).source })\b/i
whole_words_regex.to_s # => "(?i-mx:\\b(?:ore|sit|ad|sint||lore)\\b)"

# find the first hit...
search_text[whole_words_regex] # => "sit"

# find all partial word hits...
search_text.scan(partial_words_regex) # => ["Lore", "sit", "ad", "ore", "lore", "ad", "lore", "sint", "est"]

# find all whole word hits...
search_text.scan(whole_words_regex) # => ["sit", "ad", "sint", "est"]
```

Putting it all in context:

```
string_1 = "a monkey is an animal. dogs are fun"
arrays_of_strings_to_check_against = ['banana', 'fruit', 'animal', 'dog']
string_1[Regexp.union(arrays_of_strings_to_check_against)] # => "animal"
string_1.scan(Regexp.union(arrays_of_strings_to_check_against)) # => ["animal", "dog"]
```

Comment: Note that your final "in context" example does not match the requirements of whole words (though you do cover this with the `\b` version).

Comment: Note further that `/\b#{Regexp.union(…)\b/i` does **not** create a case-insensitive regex. As seen in your source, the alternation in the middle is forced to be case-sensitive.

Comment: I added a tweak to add the case-insensitive matching. As for the last part not matching the word boundaries, some things are left as an exercise deliberately since the code above did show how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_string
  arrays_of_string_to_check_against.each do |item|
      is_include = string_1.include?(item)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(string_1.scan(/\w+/) & arrays_of_strings_to_check_against).size > 0
```